# How to clone js object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

How to clone js object with out reference like these:

```
{ ID: _docEl,
  Index: next,
  DocName: _el
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Edit:*** New visitors should probably head to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).  There is a new (as of this writing) browser supported function called [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) that will be useful as browsers and engines adopt it.

Still consider the additional considerations I write below:

---

You'll have to iterate over the object and make copies of all its properties.

And then if any of its properties are also objects, assuming you want to clone those too, you'll have to recurse into them.

There's various methods for doing this here:
[What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Doing this isn't a perfect copy - depending on how it's done the new object won't inherit the original object's relationship to its prototype and you won't be able to maintain the same distinction between copied properties that were from the prototypal chain or from the object itself.  And built-in objects (like DOM nodes) won't copy properly.  In the case of DOM nodes you can clone those with their own `cloneNode()`.

**Additional considerations**

Consider whether your application really needs to clone the object or whether some other design might be appropriate.

Cloning an object by copying all its properties will create two separate copies of all its properties, and if you modify one's properties the other object won't change.  If you don't need this to be the case, simply copying the object will suffice.

You can also consider using prototypes (or the newer class syntax) and `new`  which effectively creates objects with a set of properties from a prototype that can be overridden naturally or have fall-back to those in the prototype.

Or, finally, if you wanted to add properties or methods to the new object without affecting the original object, can you just encapsulate object A into object B, that is, have object A as a property in object B, so that you can still get the reference to the original object as b.a.*property*, but can add properties to b alone as b.*property*.

Comment: Note too that this isn't one-size-fits-all - this is unlikely to do anything useful for built-in objects like DOM nodes where you'd want to use cloneNode() method, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I'd do it, based on [thomasrutter's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474697/how-to-clone-js-object/3474724#3474724) (untested code):

```
function cloneObj(obj) {
    var clone = {};

    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj[i] && typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            clone[i] = cloneObj(obj[i]);
        } else {
            clone[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: `obj.i` will not work, you will access to the `"i"` property literally, you need to use the bracket notation, e.g. `obj[i]`

Comment: This does not seem right. cloneObject({ name: null }) => {"name":{}}

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery.extend:

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

The following post is so helpful:

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript JS object clone

```
Object._clone = function(obj) {
  var clone, property, value;
  if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return obj;
  }
  clone = typeof obj.pop === 'function' ? [] : {};
  clone.__proto__ = obj.__proto__;
  for (property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      value = obj.property;
      if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        clone[property] = Object._clone(value);
      } else {
        clone[property] = obj[property];
      }
    }
  }
  return clone;
};
```

CoffeeScript JS object clone

```
# Object clone
Object._clone = (obj) ->
  return obj if not obj or typeof(obj) isnt 'object'
  clone = if typeof(obj.pop) is 'function' then [] else {}

  # deprecated, but need for instanceof method
  clone.__proto__ = obj.__proto__

  for property of obj
    if obj.hasOwnProperty property
      # clone properties
      value = obj.property
      if value and typeof(value) is 'object'
        clone[property] = Object._clone(value)
      else
        clone[property] = obj[property]

  clone
```

Now you can try to do that

```
A = new TestKlass
B = Object._clone(A)
B instanceof TestKlass => true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function objToClone(obj){
  return (new Function("return " + obj))
}
```

Comment: Ew, eval()! Not sure this would work either, unless obj has a meaningful toString() method.

Comment: would that not return a reference?