# Passing Javascript object attribute to a function-Call by value

Tags: javascript

I've created a Javscript prototypal object with a range of attributes. And I need to pass some of these attributes to a function. The function processes the attributes and returns some result.

```
function ObjCt(id,data) {
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
}
```

So, I'm trying to pass the data of the chart object to a function. Im calling it as:

```
var obj=new ObjCt(id,data);
process(obj.id,obj.data);
```

I read from somewhere that passing a value in JS results in a call by value and passing an object results in a call by reference. Here I am trying to call by value, but, seems whatever processing happens in the `process()` function is reflected in the object `obj`.

I checked the variable received in the process function using `typeof` and it comes up as 'object' and not variable. So, what can I do to pass this data as a value?

**Edit**

I found a rather tiresome workaround. `id` is primitive and `data` is a JSON object. So, I tried this in the `process()` function

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Apparently, all references were slashed here. I have a working implementation now, but, Id still love to see if there is an easier way for passing an attribute as a value.

**Edit**

Solved the problem. As per Paul's answer, tried a normal step by step cloning and another alternative using jquery extend method which goes like this

```
var object=$.extend(true,{},oldObject);
```

and passed the newly created object to the `process()` function.

Please refer this link: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: Are `id` and `data` primitive?

Comment: What you want to do is clone the object.  You can read more about it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774008/cloning-a-javascript-object

Comment: Sorry for missing that: id is primitive and data is JSON.

Comment: @Smeegs: Seems an awful lot of work for such a small result. Is there really no other way?

Comment: Actual JSON (a string) or what everyone thinks JSON is (an object)?

Comment: Not a string, definitely an object.

Comment: @MklRjv, I like your workaround.  But it's essentially another way to clone.  Unfortunately, that's the nature of objects in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *JavaScript*, primitives (*Number, String*) are passed *ByVal* and *Objects* (including *Array, Function*) are passed *ByRef*.

Most of the time this makes no difference, however you can experience problems when using methods which modify an *Object* without taking into consideration you may want it elsewhere, too.

To get around this, `clone` your *Object* before passing it into such a method.

*Array* has the native `Array.prototype.slice` to clone, for *Objects* you need to loop over keys and recurse over the properties.

---

Custom function to clone, lets you extend it to do more *Objects* via `instanceof` testing

```
function clone(o) {
    var o2 = {}, k;
    if (typeof o !== 'object')
        return o;
    if (o instanceof Array)
        return o.slice().map(clone);
    if (o instanceof Date)
        return new Date(o);
    for (k in o)
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, k))
            o2[k] = clone(o[k]);
    return o2;
}
```

---

Cloning via *JSON*, only things which can be written in *JSON* are supported

```
function clone(o) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

---

Pretending to clone by using inheritance
This **will not** protect `foo.bar.baz = primitive`, but **will** protect `foo.bar = primitive` so how good a choice it is for you depends on what the *Object* looks like or what is being done to it.

```
function pseudoclone(o) {
    return Object.create(o);
}
```

---

Don't try to clone functions, it will go horribly wrong. If you *need* to modify them somehow, wrap them.

Comment: Thnaks, I implemented cloning the object using jquery's extend method var object = $.extend(true, {}, object)

Answer (score 0):

Are you attached to that approach only?

```
 var Chart=function(id,data){
     this.ObjCt = function () {
          this.id = id;
          this.data = data;
     }
 }
```

then

```
  var obj=new Chart(id,data);
   obj.ObjCt();
  //process(obj.id,obj.data);
```

Comment: Chart is not related to this. Was a typo. Changed it in the question. Very sorry.

Comment: ok! So Just a question: Why don't you try this?

  `var ObjCt=function(id,data){this.id=id;this.data=data;}` and call with `var obj=new ObjCt(id,data); //process(obj.id,obj.data);`

Comment: @Bellash `data` is still a _reference_ all the way through that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is primitive and `data` is an object:

```
function ObjCt(id, data){
    this.id = id;
    this.data = eval(data.toSource());
}
```

This will clone the object held in `data` with simple trick.